# Play youtube video in asp.net website from url

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, youtube

I have funcional code to play youtube video only from url (like youtube.com/watch?v=....). I used it from this [article](http://manish4dotnet.blogspot.cz/2013/06/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-your.html). However it doesnt work with shorten urls (like youtu.be/....). Is it posible to do it both ways?

```
 Protected Sub SetVideoForPlay()
    'YouTube Video URL
    Dim youtubeUrl As String = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=gfedwjAOMZI&NR=1"

    Dim vCode As String = youtubeUrl.Substring(youtubeUrl.LastIndexOf("v=") + 2)
    If vCode.Contains("&") Then
        vCode = vCode.Substring(0, vCode.LastIndexOf("&"))
    End If

    Dim sHtml As String = "<object width='{0}' height='{1}' data='http://www.youtube.com/v/{2}&autoplay=0' codetype='application/x-shockwave-flash'>" & vbCr & vbLf & "  &ltparam name='movie' value='http://           www.youtube.com/v/{2}&autoplay=0'></param></object>"
    'define frame size
    Dim sWidth As String = "500px"
    Dim sHeight As String = "500px"

    'insert code to the Div
    divVideo.InnerHtml = [String].Format(sHtml, sWidth, sHeight, vCode)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortened URL is actually a 3rd-party redirect to the YouTube video.  So I think you will need to find out which URL the shortened link (youtu.be or whatever) points to, then use that URL (the one at youtube.com) to display the video.